# Using a recursive CTE in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, view, common-table-expression

Having a typical parent/child hierarchy table it's a common thing to query it using [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
 with CTE  as (
    select Id, ProviderId, ConsumerId
    from T1
    where ProviderId in (2, 3, 9)

    union all
    select T1.Id, T1.ProviderId, T1.ConsumerId
    from T1  
    join CTE on C.ProviderId = CTE.ConsumerId 
)
select * from CTE
```

Is it possible to create a view based on this query so that one can do:

```
select * from MagicView where ProviderId in (2,3,9)
```

In other words, can we somehow extract parameters from the anchor part of the CTE to create a generic view?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do. What is the problem? Put the cte inside a view? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7239/transact-sql-using-with-in-create-view

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it sounds like he is asking if a recursive cte can be in a view definition.  Your link says a cte can.  I don't see why a recursive cte wouldn't work, but I have never tried it. UserControl just give it a try its only a couple more lines of code CREATE VIEW AS and your first chunk is almost all you would need.

Comment: @UserControl this article says you can but you might need to do it without MAXRECURSION in the view definition itself http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2010/04/12/maxrecursion-with-a-cte-in-a-view/

Comment: You want to pass the parameters to the CTE from the outside? How about using an inline table valued function with a TVP parameter instead of a view?

Comment: @JamesZ good catch on the parameters in the cte didn't see that I agree a Table Valued Function with a Table Value Parameter seems the way to go to me too.  Unless you want the entire recursed table from the view and you have a large dataset and need performance then I might try and indexed view.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to hard code any parameters. I'm aware of TVF but I wonder if I can have a recursive view to apply the parameters to. Btw, you can't have an index on a view that has a CTE in its definition.

Comment: Ahh good to know UserControl I haven't tried it yet actually I have almost car blanch on schema so I don't generally use views at all.  For the TVF I would pass the paramenters to it and have the cte definition in their.  If you really want the cte in a view it sounds like you can do it without MAXRECURSION being specified.  There are probably a few techniques for Table Value Parameters you can search for if you haven't use one but I just have a TVF that splits delimited string and then join on the TVF so you can do everything in the same TVF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function (
    @ProviderId int
)
RETURNS @ProviderTable TABLE 
(
    Id int NULL, 
    ProviderId int NULL,
    ConsumerId int NULL
)
AS 
BEGIN
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT  Id, 
                ProviderId, 
                ConsumerId
        FROM T1
        WHERE ProviderId in (@ProviderId)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.Id, 
                t.ProviderId, 
                t.ConsumerId
        FROM T1 t 
        INNER JOIN cte c 
            ON t.ProviderId = c.ConsumerId 
    )

    INSERT INTO @ProviderTable
    SELECT * FROM cte;

    RETURN;
END;
```

Than create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS 
SELECT m.*
FROM Providers p
CROSS APPLY my_function (p.ProviderId) m
```

After that you can SELECT from view whatever you need:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_view 
WHERE ProviderId in (2,3,9)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do Table Valued Route

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MVParam_tvf](@ParameterString nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1)= ',')
RETURNS @VALUES TABLE (Param nvarchar(4000))AS

Figure out your code preference to spilt delimited string to table

END

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MagicView_tvf
(   
    @ParameterString  NVARCHAR(4000)
    ,@Delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    with CTE  as (
       select Id, ProviderId, ConsumerId
       from
          T1 t
          INNER JOIN MVParam_tvf (@ParameterString, @Delimiter) p
          ON CAST(t.ProviderId AS VARCHAR(10)) = p.OutPutColumn

       union all
       select T1.Id, T1.ProviderId, T1.ConsumerId
       from T1  
       join CTE on C.ProviderId = CTE.ConsumerId 
    )
    select * from CTE
)
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.MagicView_tvf ('2,3,9')
```

If you want to go the view route create the view without the where line on anchor part of cte and then when you call it write your where statement on that query.