SQL insert into table with case statement
I'm trying to set up a table starting from a table like the following:
Table Jobs:



Jobs
Desc
InitDate
EndDate
MonthlyHours




A143
W
01/01/24
31/03/24
4


B458
X
10/02/24
30/04/24
6


R589
Y
01/01/24
31/05/24
8


H756
Z
08/03/24
30/06/24
2



NOTE: date in format dd/mm/yy
Needing a final table like the following (or similar):
Table JobsAggregation:



Jobs
Desc
MonthYear
MonthlyHours




A143
W
01/24
4


A143
W
02/24
4


A143
W
03/24
4


B458
X
02/24
6


B458
X
03/24
6


B458
X
04/24
6


R589
Y
01/24
8


R589
Y
02/24
8


R589
Y
03/24
8


R589
Y
04/24
8


R589
Y
05/24
8


H756
Z
03/24
2


H756
Z
04/24
2


H756
Z
05/24
2


H756
Z
06/24
2



I need this set-up to hours per months and using it into a visual object in PowerBI where i can identify how much time i spend per each jobs for every month:
January    12
February   18
March      20
April      16
May        10
June        2

Thanks
I cannot find a solution for this.

see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275905/sql-date-range-broken-down-by-individual-month-and-year-while-maintaining-the

For this case you can use recursive CTE expression like:
with R as (
    select Jobs, [Desc], DATETRUNC(month, InitDate) MonthYear, MonthlyHours from T 
    union all
    select T.Jobs, T.[Desc], DATEADD(month, 1, MonthYear) MonthYear, T.MonthlyHours 
    from T
    join R ON T.Jobs = r.Jobs WHERE DATETRUNC(month, T.EndDate) > R.MonthYear
) select * from R 
order by Jobs, MonthYear;

This query get each row of your table and iterate it till condition will be reached.
Check it here: https://sqlize.online/s/Ws

This is ok in SQL 2022, but my production SQL is running the version 13.0.5108.50, how can i tanslate the code DATATRUNC?

@ThomasSoffiati, look this https://sqlize.online/s/ts

You will be able to see both result sets in the solution I sent yesterday.

Using suggestions from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275905/sql-date-range-broken-down-by-individual-month-and-year-while-maintaining-the
;with dates ([Date]) as (
    Select CAST('2024-01-01' as date) as [Date] -- Put the start date here

    union all 

    Select dateadd(month, 1, [Date])
    from dates
    where [Date] <= CAST('2024-06-30' as date) -- Put the end date here 
)
select Jobs
    ,  [Desc]
    ,  right('00' +CAST(DATEPART(mm,[DATE]) as Varchar(2)),2) + '/' + right(CAST(DATEPART(yy,[DATE]) as varchar(4)),2) as MonthYear 
    ,  MonthlyHours
    from dates d
    join #temp t on d.Date >=  DATEFROMPARTS ( year(convert(datetime,t.InitDate,3)), month(convert(datetime,t.InitDate,3)), 1 )  
        and d.Date <= convert(datetime,t.EndDate,3)
  ORDER BY [Desc], DATEPART(YEAR,[DATE]), DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]) 

fiddle



Jobs
Desc
MonthYear
MonthlyHours




A143
W
01/24
4


A143
W
02/24
4


A143
W
03/24
4


B458
X
02/24
6


B458
X
03/24
6


B458
X
04/24
6


R589
Y
01/24
8


R589
Y
02/24
8


R589
Y
03/24
8


R589
Y
04/24
8


R589
Y
05/24
8


H756
Z
03/24
2


H756
Z
04/24
2


H756
Z
05/24
2


H756
Z
06/24
2




Gotcha! now i have the view with these field, but i need to put the option (maxrecursion 0) to see the data.
Is there a way to exclude the maxrecursion option to see the data into the view?

Please explain why you need to include maxrecursion at all? It should work without it. maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886502/using-a-recursive-cte-in-a-view

Here is a solution using Power BI Power Query:
let
  Source = Jobs,
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "MonthSeries", each { 0..(Date.Year([EndDate])-Date.Year([InitDate]) + Date.Month([EndDate]) - Date.Month([InitDate])) }),
  #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "MonthSeries"),
  #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "MonthYear", each #date(Date.Year([InitDate]), Date.Month([InitDate]) + [MonthSeries], 1), type date),
  #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"InitDate", "EndDate", "MonthSeries"})
in
  #"Removed Columns"


DECLARE @MonthHourList TABLE (Jobs varchar(4), [Desc] varchar(1), MonthYear date, MonthlyHours int);
DECLARE @JobTable TABLE (Jobs varchar(4), [Desc] varchar(1), IniDate date, EndDate date, MonthlyHours int)
;
INSERT INTO @JobTable VALUES
        ('A143', 'W', '01/01/24', '03/31/24',   4)
    ,   ('B458', 'X', '02/10/24', '04/30/24',   6)
    ,   ('R589', 'Y', '01/01/24', '05/31/24',   8)
    ,   ('H756', 'Z', '03/08/24', '06/30/24',   2)
;


WITH T  AS
    (
        SELECT  
                Jobs
            ,   [Desc]
            ,   IniDate
            ,   EndDate
            ,   MonthlyHours
        FROM    @JobTable
    UNION ALL
        SELECT  
                Jobs
            ,   [Desc]
            ,   IniDate =   DATEADD(MONTH, 1, T.IniDate)
            ,   EndDate
            ,   MonthlyHours
        FROM    T
        WHERE   T.EndDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, 1, T.IniDate)
    )

INSERT INTO @MonthHourList
SELECT  
            Jobs
        ,   [Desc]
        ,   MonthYear   =   T.IniDate
        ,   MonthlyHours
FROM        T
ORDER BY 
            Jobs
        ,   IniDate

SELECT  
            Jobs
        ,   [Desc]
        ,   MonthYear   =   FORMAT(MonthYear, 'MM/yy')
        ,   MonthlyHours
FROM        @MonthHourList
ORDER BY 
            Jobs
        ,   MonthYear
;

SELECT  
        MonthID         =   MONTH(MonthYear)
    ,   [MonthName]     =   DATENAME(MONTH, MonthYear)
    ,   [MonthHours]    =   SUM(MonthlyHours)
FROM    @MonthHourList
GROUP BY 
        MONTH(MonthYear)
    ,   DATENAME(MONTH, MonthYear)
ORDER BY MonthID    

